# finding the closest K points from origin

Tags: java, list, 2d

I have the following problem: given a list of point coordinate return the k closest point to the origin, the return type should be a list of coordinate.
I have worked on this code but need to fix the return type smallestkpoints to match the return type of closestPoints method.
any thoughts?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.lang.Double;

public class ClosestKPoints {

    //distance to origin
    public static Double distance(Integer x, Integer y) {

        double powX = Math.pow(x, 2);
        double powY = Math.pow(y, 2);

        return (Double)(Math.sqrt(powX + powY));
    }


    public static List<List<Integer>> closestPoints(int k, List<List<Integer>> points, int all) {

        Hashtable<Double,List<Integer>> pt = new Hashtable();
        Double [] dt = new Double[all];//where we store distances later to be sorted
        List<List<Integer>> smallestKPoints;//to be used as return result


        for (int i = 0; i <points.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> in = points.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < in.size() - 1; j++) {
                Integer x = in.get(j);
                Integer y = in.get(j + 1);
                pt.put(distance( x, y), points.get(i));
                dt[i] = distance(x, y);
            } 

        }

        Arrays.sort(dt);

        for (int n = 0; n < k; n++) {
            List<Integer> smallestKPoints = pt.get(dt[n]);
        }

        return smallestKPoints;

    }
}
```

Comment: just define List<Integer> smallestKPoints out of the loop

Comment: I did it before and forgot to put it in the code

Comment: the error I am getting reside within this block:                                               
                      for (int n=0; n<k;n++) {
   List<Integer> smallestKPoints = pt.get(dt[n]);
   }
   
           return smallestKPoints;

Comment: From what i see, return type of `List<Integer> smallestKPoints` matches type of `List<Integer> closestPoints`. I don't understand your problem.

Comment: the return type should be list<List<Integer>>

Comment: I have updated the code, please refresh and check.

Comment: That is not a good approach. Create yourself a `Point` class with `x` and `y` coordinates. Then you can use `HashMap<Integer, Point>` to store and return all points matching criteria.

Comment: Unless it is required to use a `List<Integer>`, you should use a `java.awt.Point` instead. Beyond that: The `Map`-based approach is brittle, and will not work as expected for points that have the same distance. You could/should create a `Comparator<Point, Point>` that compares the points by their distance, as in `return Double.compare(p0.distance(origin), p1.distance(origin));`. No need for maps at all.

Comment: yes the return type should be List<List<Integer>>